# How to fix the error stating React Native Firebase was successfully found, but the main module could not be resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am trying to get the code output to show without any errors, but every time I run this code I get an error stating the "iOS Bundling failed. While trying to resolve module `firebase` from file `C:\Internship\src\App.js`, the package `C:\Internship\node_modules\firebase\package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`C:\Internship\node_modules\firebase\index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- C:\Internship\node_modules\firebase\index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
- C:\Internship\node_modules\firebase\index\index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)"

---

```js
//Importing Libraries to create App
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {Header} from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

//Creating App class
class App extends Component{
    //Initalizing Firebase 
    componentWillMount(){
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyDaAOmCb2Agiu7JRLlOUG0Mv7O4VxH-Od8',
            authDomain: 'oakpark-service-app.firebaseapp.com',
            projectId: 'oakpark-service-app',
            storageBucket: 'oakpark-service-app.appspot.com',
            messagingSenderId: '662166215544',
            appId: '1:662166215544:web:e433baacc7d1a9c219068d',
            measurementId: 'G-PZ6LLVFNFD'
          });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Header headerText="Login/Sign Up" />
                <LoginForm />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

//Exporting App class to use in different files
export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi AKoundinya, welcome to Stack Overflow. 

The issue you're having looks like a dependency issue with the firebase module installation.

Have you followed the Reactive Native Firebase installation instructions at https://rnfirebase.io/, ensuring all of the prerequisite steps have been completed? If you could attempt to retry these steps and provide details on any issues or errors you experience this would be helpful to identify the cause of the problem. Good luck with the internship :)

Comment: It seems like you're using Firebase JavaScript SDK.  Check the Version you're using as now there're V8 and V9. V9 are no longer supports  namespace import `import firebase from "firebase"`